# Android Gdb gcore "command not implemented for this target"

Tags: android

I am using gdb for dumping core file for an android process. I am running gdbserver on the device on tcp port and gdb client on the desktop. When i do gcore on client i get the below error.
Does any one know why i'm getting this error , any help much appreciated.

> (gdb) gcore
>   Command not implemented for this target.

The reason i'm doing this to dump process memory and extract Classes.dex file from the memory using core file. I've tried doing this using /proc/pid/mem and proc/pid/maps and dump memory  but that has too many mapped regions , i couldn't find the area where the Classes.dex file is. Any other alternate approach is also welcome. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You don't need GDB or a running process at all - just open the apk as a zip file and classes.dex will be right there.

Comment: another answer for reference: http://serverfault.com/questions/173999/dump-a-linux-processs-memory-to-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can only dump odex from memory (because dex compiled to odex for execute). But its not a big deal to convert odex to dex using baksmali-smali.

To find odex in memory you can use gdb for checking magic number for every begin-address of mapped memory(proc/pid/maps - first column):

```
gdb --batch --pid "pid_task" -ex x/s "mem_start"
```

So, when returned value equal to "dey\n036", you can dump this memory region via gdb.
Try to begin checking memory addresses from the end of file "proc/pid/maps", it will be much faster.

PS Sorry for my english, but hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

@Chris Stratton, the memory mapped classes.dex file will be different from the dex file inside apk on disk, for example in cases of packed dex files, some part of dex will be deobfuscated, question is to dump the memory mapped classes.dex file by getting the process memory.

Comment: thats correct, but the original question is still unaswered as to how to get it in right way

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GameGuardian](http://gameguardian.net/download) for this. Need root.

Memory editor tab - menu - memory dump - input 0-0 as range and folder - press ok - wait for toast `Dump end`.
Go to selected folder - open maps file - search needed odex in regions - remember start address of region - open GameGuardian - menu - memory dump - input remembered address in both field as range - press ok - wait for toast `Dump end`.
Now you have in your folder `.bin` file with dumped odex file.

Also you can find address in drop down list in GameGuardian UI. Press drop down icon on right with dump range field.

Here some video examples how to do this:

- [How to dump odex file from memory on Android -
  GameGuardian](https://gameguardian.net/forum/gallery/image/251-how-to-dump-odex-file-from-memory-on-android-gameguardian/)

Comment: looks good, if you are a developer you should rebuild it as dedicated tool , rename the tool, to AndroMemDump or something like that and also do a blog about it

Comment: @user3826306 No. I do not want this.

Comment: ,"do not want  this" ?? don't want write a dedicated tool ? or write blog ?

Comment: @user3826306, both.